# CSS: Sticky footer not working

Tags: css, sticky-footer

If you compare the following 2 pages:

Page 1: http://goldencraft.co/wp/

Page 2: http://goldencraft.co/wp/contact/

CSS: http://goldencraft.co/wp/wp-content/themes/minecraft/style.css

You'll see that when there is content, the footer isn't properly sticking. I have been trying to fix it for an hour, so I'm hoping someone can spot the problem inside the CSS, thanks.

[Example of sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit appears to be the `iframe` right before the `</body>` tag. It has a `visibility:hidden` rule, which will allow it to displace elements on the page (in comparison to `display:none`).

You can either remove it, or add the following css:

```
iframe {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: I don't see an iframe on my Chrome browser, but this solved the problem either way. Thanks.

Comment: That's odd. It's definitely there in my Chrome web inspector (that's how I found it...). Oh well, glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Now just replace to yor `#footer` **ID** in your css file

```
#footer {
    background-color: #252525;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't want it to move with the page, I want it pushed to the bottom without that stupid space below it (on contact).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

CSS

```
html,body{height:100%; width:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
#wrapper{width:100%; height:100%; min-height:100%; height:auto; margin:0 auto; margin-bottom:-100px !important; background-color:#999999;}
#push{min-height:100px;}
#footer{min-height:100px; width:100%; overflow:hidden; background-color:#FF0000;}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="push"></div><!-- do not remove -->
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```